# combine jquery elements, hiding submit button until a field changes

Tags: jquery, forms

This is probably simple to solve, but today the brain isn't playing ball. I'm trying to hide a submit button until a form element changes. To make things a little more complicated, one of the form fields is a google places autocomplete field.

Thanks to SO I was able to find a solution for hiding the submit button, adapted it a little to produce the following:

```
var $inputs = $('#searchform :input');
  $('.submits').hide()
  $inputs.on('keyup change', function() {
    $('.submits').show();
    $('.submithide').hide();
});
```

However, this didn't show the submit button when the user clicked inside the google places autocomplete field and selected a new place (without pressing a key). So, a little more searching on SO and I found that I had to call an addListener event. I have the following jquery to handle this:

```
var $inputs = $('#searchform :input');
  $('.submits').hide()
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
     $('.submits').show();
     $('.submithide').hide();

});
```

I have tested both these jqueries by themselves and they work perfectly, but the question is, how do I combine both so that all changes (place_changed, change and keyup) are recognised? I have tried:

```
var $inputs = $('#searchform :input');
  $('.submits').hide()
  google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function()); 
  $inputs.on('keyup change place_changed', function() {
    $('.submits').show();
    $('.submithide').hide();
});
```

with zero luck. can someone point me in the correct direction? many thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store a function inside a variable, then just pass the variable through as the callback function.

```
var toggleSubmits = function() {
    $('.submits').show();
    $('.submithide').hide();
}

google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', toggleSubmits);
$inputs.on('keyup change', toggleSubmits);
```

Comment: Thanks Joe. This works like a charm. However, I left out the place_changed on the line $inputs.on('keyup change place_changed', toggleSubmits);. Did you intentionally put it there, or was it a mistake? Many thanks for your contribution!!!